# How can I find a list of questions that used to have a bounty, i.e. the bounty has been awarded?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

How can I find a list of questions that used to have a bounty, i.e., the bounty has been awarded (within a particular Stack Exchange site)?

Answer (score 5):

You can try [this data.SE query I just threw together](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392065) (remove `TOP 50` to get the full list, which will take significantly longer):

```
SELECT TOP 50 PostId AS [Post Link], BountyAmount
FROM Votes
WHERE BountyAmount IS NOT NULL
```

I don't think this is possible without the data explorer.

Comment: [Fork of the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/392180/list-of-questions-with-bounties) with sorting by creation date and bounty amount.